# Convert uploaded video to Silverlight WMV

Tags: silverlight, video, upload

Can one of you smarties point me to some beginner content for converting an uploaded video to WMV? I've got a file upload, and database entry all done, but I'm finding information / tutorials on Windows Media Encoder 9 scarce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Windows Media Encoder 9 Series SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=000A16F5-D62B-4303-BB22-F0C0861BE25B) yet?

Comment: This is a good start. Do you know of any good beginner tutorials? Personally I find Microsoft documentation to be overwhelming at times.